# ProducesAttribute causes "No output formatter was found for content types"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

Consider this simple controller action:

```
[HttpGet("{imageId}")]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 604800)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[Produces("image/jpeg")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImageAsync(int imageId)
{
    if (imageId <= 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    byte[] imageBytes = await _imageProvider.GetImageAsync(
        imageId,
        Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (imageBytes is null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return File(imageBytes, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
}
```

This method works fine, however in telemetry I am getting this for every call:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor: Warning: No output formatter was found for content types 'image/jpeg, image/jpeg' to write the response.

Simply commenting out the `ProducesAttribute` prevents the telemetry from being logged.

I want to keep `ProducesAttribute` because it enables my Swagger UI page to work. In Swagger it shows this API has an expected output media type of `image/jpeg`. If I remove the attribute it changes to `text/plain` and it doesn't render correctly.

So the question is, how can I fix this controller action to not create a bunch of unnecessary telemetry, while also allowing Swagger UI to work correctly?

Comment: it's clearly that you don't have an `IOutputFormatter` for the content type `image/jpeg`. You need to create your own custom `IOutputFormatter` to handle that content type. In case of using such a custom output formatter, your controller action need to return plain data (e.g: byte[], ...) so that your output formater can write it to the response stream correctly (so you don't need to use `File` method to return a `FileResult`, just return the bytes array). In this case the `SwaggerUI` cannot know the returned type of the action but I believe that there should be some other way to let it know.

Comment: instead of trying to create your custom `IOutputFormatter` (so you can use `ProducesAttribute` to let the swagger ui know about the returned content type) you can try to let the swagger ui know that info by somehow (not just via the `ProducesAttribute`). I do believe that there should be such a way. The `File` method is really convenient, we don't have to avoid it just because we need to support swagger ui. So if swagger ui does not support another kind of mechanism to read the content type metadata, then it's just badly designed. We as users simply cannot do much about that.